# What's the best way to structure REST uri's for entities chained through multiple joins?

Tags: web-services, rest, asp.net-web-api

What's the best way to structure REST URIs for entities chained through multiple joins?  For example, say I have a datamodel with tables A, B, C, D. I have a web method that gets all of the D data stored for A, joined through B and C.  What would be the best way to structure a REST URI for this?  Would it be?:

A/{AId}/Ds

Could I exclude B and C from the URI representation since they would not be relevant for the purpose of this particular request? Or is there some other URI structure I should use for this scenario?

Comment: Does, my answer solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If a `D` is a subresource of `A` then the following URI will do the job:

`As/{ID}/Ds`

(as you wrote, but remember about *collection* of resources). There's no need to expose `B` and `C` to the client directly if they do not play any meaningful role. And remember that REST API is not (and should be not) in 1:1 relation with DB model.